# in kernel driver, why does not mmap work in procfs?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I implement mmap function, and mount it to file operation.
And create a file in /proc.
but when I insmod, it responses "mmap_example2: Unknown symbol _page_cachable_default
insmod: can't insert 'mmap_example2.ko': unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter"

when i remove mmap function from file operations, it can be inserted.
so do i neglect something? how to make mmap work in procfs?

the code is below

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/mm.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/vmalloc.h>

#define FILE_NAME "test"

typedef enum ALLOC_TYPE
{
    KMALLOC = 0, VMALLOC, MAX_ALLOC_TYPE,
} eAllocType;

static unsigned char array[10]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
static unsigned char *buffer;

static int file_open(struct inode *pInode, struct file *pFile)
{
    printk("%s\n", __FUNCTION__);
    return 0;
}

static int file_release(struct inode *pInode, struct file *pFile)
{
    printk("%s\n", __FUNCTION__);
    return 0;
}

static int file_mmap(struct file *pFile, struct vm_area_struct* pVMA)
{
    unsigned long page;
    unsigned char i;
    unsigned long start = (unsigned long)pVMA->vm_start;
    unsigned long size = (unsigned long)(pVMA->vm_end - pVMA->vm_start);

    page = virt_to_phys(buffer);

    if(remap_pfn_range(pVMA,start,page>>PAGE_SHIFT,size,PAGE_SHARED))
    return -1;

     for(i=0;i<10;i++)
         buffer[i] = array[i];
     return 0;
}

struct file_operations file_ops =
{
    .open       = file_open,
    .release    = file_release,
    .mmap       = file_mmap,
};

static int mmap_example2_init(void)
{
    struct proc_dir_entry* entry = NULL;
    printk("%s init\n", __FUNCTION__);
    if(!(entry = create_proc_entry(FILE_NAME,0666,NULL)))
    {
    printk("%s fail to create proc file\n",__FUNCTION__);
    return -EINVAL;
    }
    entry->proc_fops = &file_ops;
    buffer = kmalloc(10,GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!buffer)
    {
    printk("allocate mem error\n");
    return -1;
    }
    SetPageReserved(virt_to_page(buffer));
    return 0;
}

static void mmap_example2_exit(void)
{
    printk("%s exit\n", __FUNCTION__);
    remove_proc_entry(FILE_NAME,NULL);
    ClearPageReserved(virt_to_page(buffer));
    kfree(buffer);
}

module_init(mmap_example2_init);
module_exit(mmap_example2_exit);
```

Answer (score 0):

To add file_operations use proc_create instead of create_proc_entry and pass it your file_operation object

```
static struct file_operations myops = 
{
    .read = myread,
    .mmap = mymmap,
};
static int simple_init(void)
{
    ent=proc_create("mytest",0660,NULL,&myops);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "hello, module %d...\n",irq);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it does not work. still responses "mmap_example2: Unknown symbol _page_cachable_default insmod: can't insert 'mmap_example2.ko': unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter"

Comment: what is the kernel version

Comment: it still does not work, using proc_create. kernel version is 2.6.27.29. Which config should be enable?

Comment: Try first to leave mmap empty (just returns 0) and see if you get the same error. if not add just virt_to_phys and test it again

Comment: When I leave mmap empty, it works. When this function has remap_pfn_range, the error occurs. so this function makes this happens. But I put this mmap into char device driver, and it works successfully. But I still dont know why procfs can use mmap?

Comment: strange... I test it also with user code and its ok - the only different is that I'm running 3.10 kernel. if it works for you with char device its not a missing configuration. why you don't use a dummy char device instead of proc? actually the purpose of proc is diagnostics and configuration (on the older proc_entry struct you could add read and write functions only)

Comment: I have found the point just now. when add MODULE_LICENSE, it can insmod normally. And I will verify user program work or not latter.